# CiviVolunteer: Find Volunteer Opportunities

Tags: civivolunteer

would love to be able to enable/disable search options. Currently there is:
Between (date ranges), Role, With, Search by Location.
Would like to disable "Search by Location" and replace with "Project".
Also the ability to change the order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Karen-Ann,

Thanks for your question. StackExchange is not really the best place for feature requests. In case you wish to pursue this further, I have [created an issue for you](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/issues/493) in the GitHub project for CiviVolunteer.

To provide the level of configurability you describe would require a significant investment of developer hours (though some of the fruit hang lower than others). These enhancements are not currently on the roadmap for CiviVolunteer, but you may be able to hire a developer to implement them for you.

If you're really pressed to hide the "Search by Location" field, an easy way to do this is via your site's theme; the following CSS should do the trick:

```
.crm-vol-opp-search .crm-vol-proximity {
  display: none;
}
```

Note that the elements will still be rendered in the HTML, but they will be hidden from view.